# Different package versions in same suite?

Tags: debian, package-management

I recently got this this surprising result:

```
evolution-data-server-common:
  Installed: 2.30.3-2
  Candidate: 2.30.3-2
  Version table:
     3.0.0-1 0
        -10 http://debian.mirror.ac.za/debian/ experimental/main i386 Packages
     2.91.92-1 0
        -10 http://debian.mirror.ac.za/debian/ experimental/main i386 Packages
     2.32.2-4 0
        -10 http://debian.mirror.ac.za/debian/ wheezy/main i386 Packages
        -10 http://debian.mirror.ac.za/debian/ unstable/main i386 Packages
 *** 2.30.3-2 0
        900 file:/home/wena/.repo_bin/ stable/main i386 Packages
        900 http://debian.mirror.ac.za/debian/ squeeze/main i386 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

That implies that I have the different versions of `evolution-data-server-common` in Experimental, which I thought wasn't 'possible'. What's happening? Is this a bug maybe?

Comment: I can't see 3.0.0-1 on [your mirror](http://debian.mirror.ac.za/debian/pool/main/e/evolution-data-server/).

Comment: Ah.  They're doing weird things for Gnome 3 so it doesn't overwrite Gnome 2.  e-d-s-common 3 is in `pool/main/e/evolution-data-server3` on your mirror.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look in the [Packages file](http://debian.mirror.ac.za/debian/dists/experimental/main/binary-i386/Packages.gz).

It will be so that you can have Gnome 2 or Gnome 3.

`apt-cache rdepends evolution-data-server-common` may also help.

```
Package: evolution-data-server-common
Priority: optional
Section: gnome
Source: evolution-data-server
Version: 2.91.92-1
Filename: pool/main/e/evolution-data-server/evolution-data-server-common_2.91.92-1_all.deb

Package: evolution-data-server-common
Priority: optional
Section: gnome
Source: evolution-data-server3
Version: 3.0.0-1
Filename: pool/main/e/evolution-data-server3/evolution-data-server-common_3.0.0-1_all.deb
```

Comment: But that **2.91.x** version was a development version leading to **3.0**. The last GNOME 2 versions are **2.32.x**

Comment: Don't ask me, ask the package maintainer.